# different Date in Meteor client VS MongoDB saved date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In js file I have the variable

```
date=new Date()
```

which returns the current date correctly e.g.

> date Thu Jan 30 2020 12:07:34 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard
>   Time)

when calling the save method to insert the data in MongoDB

```
saveMethod:function(SessionId,date,methodName){
            ExperimentData.insert({SessionId:SessionId, Date:date, MethodName:methodName})
            return true;
        },
```

I realize that the data field date is 2 hours before on the MongoDB, why does this happen?How can I save the correct current Date on the mongodb?
[image]

Comment: Hey, its the ISO time, there is no problem you'll just need to convert it on frontend

Comment: @user2829319 is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo Dates are ISO date, which are always in UTC: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Your local Date will however be relative to this date based on the local timezone settings. Thus there is no need to save the date explicitly different.

If you want to display the UTC date in your local time zone use `toLocaleDate`:

```js
const doc = MyCollection.findOne(docId)
const date = new Date(doc.Date)
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString()) // converted to locale
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString